# Change the view of a UIViewController dynamically in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have 2 Custom View classes(`CustomView_A, CustomView_B`) derived from `UIView`. I have `UIViewController` that should be able to switch between views at run-time..

What so far, I have done is.. in the Storyboard, I am using `CustomView_A` class as the View class.

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) CustomView_A *customView_A;
```

Now I have the second `CustomView_B` class and I want to change view of `MyViewController`'s view to `CustomView_B` at run-time.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance..

Comment: u can simply hide CustomView_A and show CustomView_B using UIViewAnimation!

Comment: Your CustomView_A/B is in Nib/storyboard/Code? its quite easy just set you `self.view = CustomView_B instance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, here is the code as you want -

in your  `MyViewController.h` put -

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomView_A *customView_A;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomView_B *customView_B;

-(void)switchView; // to switch the views.
```

in your `MyViewController.m` put -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.customView_A = [[CustomView_A alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.customView_A.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIButton *trigger = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; // Just take this button so that your switchView methods will get called on click of this method.
    [trigger setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 30)];
    [trigger setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [trigger addTarget:self action:@selector(switchView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.customView_A addSubview:trigger];

    [self.view addSubview:self.customView_A];

    self.customView_B = [[CustomView_B alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    self.customView_B.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.customView_B.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.customView_B];
}

- (void)switchView
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:10 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.customView_A.hidden = YES;
        self.customView_B.hidden = NO;
    } completion:nil];

}
```

Do opposite when you again want to switch the views.

Answer (score 2):

Don't. What you're describing is an essential misunderstanding of UIViewController. Once a UIViewController instance has a `view`, that is its `view` forever.

If you want two different views then either:

- Use two view controllers (for example, you can *present* view controller B and its view on top of view controller A and its view, using a modal segue), or
- Make at least one of those views not be owned by a view controller: just place that view in front of the other view and later remove it again, at will.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)changeView {
       if (self.customView_A.hidden == YES) {
            self.customView_A.hidden = NO;
            self.customView_B.hidden = YES;
            //You should use a UIView animation here to do this.
       }
       else {
            self.customView_A.hidden = YES;
            self.customView_B.hidden = NO;
            //Same here
       )
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad` add the view to `CGRectZero`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       self.customView_A = [[CustomView_A alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
       [self.view addSubview:self.customView_A];
       //do the same with the other custom view
}
```

Sorry if the code is a little faulty, I didn't use `Xcode` to type this up.